# Remove flash of login component when using Firebase authentication (React)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I successfully implement login and registration features on my app, using firebase auth. However when a user is logged in and they reload the page, the app flashes the login component for a second (sometimes almost 2 seconds) before displaying the app homepage.

Do you think this is a react bug or a firebase bug? Anyone else experience this issue? What can i do to fix this?

What have i tried? Nothing, there isn't really anything i CAN try as firebase just seems to take too long to detect authentication.

Answer (score 1):

More information is needed, but sounds like your app defaults to the login component and then once authenticated shows a different component.

Likely you need to put some logic on the mount of your app to show a loading spinner or other such UI while authe to stop is checked.

Comment: Ah yes this is a good idea. dont know why i didn't think of that. thanks.